# How long can an uncooked roast sit on the counter?

Tags: roast

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it safe to cook a steak that was left out (raw) for 7 hours?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/15557/is-it-safe-to-cook-a-steak-that-was-left-out-raw-for-7-hours)

My husband pulled a moose roast out of the freezer, marinated it in the fridge for 2 days and then put it in the slow cooker this morning. I just got home and noticed that he never plugged in the slow cooker, so this defrosted roast has been sitting on our counter for 7 hours. I plugged the slow cooker in and turned it on high. There's no dairy products in the marinade. Are we going to get sick if we eat this roast?

Comment: Welcome Kristen! We have a special page about such food safety questions: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/food-safety/info

Comment: The short answer is: That is too long. Odds are still in your favor that it will be fine but the risk that it will hurt you is not 0 anymore. You can make your own decisions about how risky food has to be before it's thrown out.

Comment: I was hoping to not have to throw it out. Thank you.

Comment: I will throw it out.